# easy_install PyOpenSSL error

Tags: openssl, pyopenssl

Any idea about what cause the error below ?

I use Linux centos with openssl-devel.i386 0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7

```
$ easy_install PyOpenSSL
Searching for PyOpenSSL
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyOpenSSL/
Reading http://launchpad.net/pyopenssl
Reading http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/
Best match: pyOpenSSL 0.13
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz#md5=767bca18a71178ca353dff9e10941929
Processing pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz
Running pyOpenSSL-0.13/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-0Dunib/pyOpenSSL-0.13/egg-dist-tmp-aV6OCC
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c: In function ‘ssl_Connection_set_context’:
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:289: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSL_set_SSL_CTX’
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c: In function ‘ssl_Connection_get_servername’:
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:313: error: ‘TLSEXT_NAMETYPE_host_name’ undeclared (first use in this function)
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:313: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:313: error: for each function it appears in.)
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:320: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSL_get_servername’
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:320: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c: In function ‘ssl_Connection_set_tlsext_host_name’:
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:346: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSL_set_tlsext_host_name’
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Just started happening to me as well.
# uname -a
Linux domU-xxxxxxxxx x.x.x.x-2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Feb 15 12:34:28 EST 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I've posted a bug report to pyOpenSSL guys and rolled back to 0.12

Answer (score 27):

In order to install it under virtualenv, you should first install the required packages.  On ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

Then you can just type:

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

Comment: should be `libffi-dev`

Comment: also libssl-dev (for me atleast...)

Comment: I think the question is clear that it is not debain based OS

Answer (score 25):

pyOpenSSL 0.13 introduced support for the (S)erver (N)ame (I)ndication TLS extension.  This extension allows clients to tell the server what hostname they expect to be talking to, allowing the server to select a suitable certificate to present.

Support for SNI was introduced in OpenSSL 0.9.8f.  Thus, pyOpenSSL 0.13 will build with OpenSSL 0.9.8f or later, but not OpenSSL 0.9.8e or earlier, where the APIs it expects to be wrapping do not exist.

Perhaps a newer version of pyOpenSSL will make these bindings optional, restoring support for OpenSSL 0.9.8e and earlier.  However, similarly, a newer version of OpenSSL will also work with pyOpenSSL 0.13.

The pyOpenSSL project issues pre-releases.  Widespread testing of pre-releases can help avoid cases like this one.  I recommend that anyone relying on pyOpenSSL subscribe to the (very low traffic) [pyOpenSSL user list](https://launchpad.net/~pyopenssl-users) (or on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=31249)) and do what testing you can when a pre-release comes out, before the release is finalized.

Comment: That's right! I had the same problem and I found it easier to install pyOpenSSL 0.12 than upgrade openssl from 0.9.8e to 0.9.8f to get 0.13 to work..

Here is the command I used:
easy_install http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12.tar.gz

Comment: Thanasis and Jean-Paul, thanks a ton for your information.  Wish I had found this page a couple of hours ago, or could give you guys a big hug for helping me out on this.  I had just about given up on getting scrapy working on Centos5.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this while trying to install Scrapy. For me, Thanasis' answer didn't work. After some more Google and randomly installing things

```
yum install python-devel
```

allowed the Scrapy install to run for me (CentOS release 6.3 (Final))

Comment: I also required the following:
`sudo yum -y install libffi-devel libssl-devel`

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly what is asked, but in **Ubuntu 12.04** it can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-openssl
```

Answer (score 5):

For me I had to install the openssl-devel libs:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

Was trying to install the cyclone/tornado/twisted python evented lib.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use the lastest `pyOpenSSL`, just rolled back to 0.12, this is the simplest way.

```
pip install pyOpenSSL==0.12
```

Check for @Jean-Paul's answer for detail.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install:

`sudo apt-get install -y python-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't install libssl-devel or libssl-dev, but this worked for me on CentOS 6 (when pyOpenSSL 0.13.1 was previously installed):

```
sudo yum -y remove pyOpenSSL.x86_64
sudo yum -y install libffi-devel
#sudo yum -y install libssl-devel 
sudo yum -y install openssl-devel 
sudo yum -y install python-devel
sudo pip install pyopenssl
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. Checking a bit we found a way to resolve it:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/845445

What you're looking for is "Philip's fix works for me on CentOS 5.6:":
https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/845445/comments/9

This worked well in our case.

Comment: In order to this don't forget to install "patch"