# Scrapy installation problems

Tags: installation, scrapy

I'm trying to install Scrapy in cygwin, and I've finally got easy_install working but it keeps giving this error message: Setup script exited with error:

```
'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm using gcc version 3.4.4. Any ideas, I'm at a loss for what to try next? Before it gives this error message it print out thousands of line about OpenSSl, I'm not sure if that means the problem is in OpenSSL or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the root problem was in pyOpenSSL and is addressed here [easy_install PyOpenSSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340784/easy-install-pyopenssl-error).

Update: For other gcc errors that I later got I found that installing gcc4 from the cygwin setup fixed it.