# Error when running conda raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error)

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am working on computer with Ubuntu 16.04. 
I have anaconda installed and was using the jupyter notebook just fine both for julia and python a couple of hours while ago. I installed/reinstalled some packages but nothing out of the ordinary.

However, after closing notebooks and then trying to open them again I get error:

```
jupyter notebook

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 16, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate, ValidationError
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/validator.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import ValidationError
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jsonschema.validators import (
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 11, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 7, in <module>
    binding = Binding()
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 89, in __init__
    self._ensure_ffi_initialized()
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 109, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
    libraries=libraries,
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.py", line 80, in build_ffi
    extra_link_args=extra_link_args,
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 437, in verify
    lib = self.verifier.load_library()
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 114, in load_library
    return self._load_library()
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 225, in _load_library
    return self._vengine.load_library()
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/vengine_cpy.py", line 158, in load_library
    raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error)
cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: importing '/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_4ed9e37dx4000d087.so': /home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_4ed9e37dx4000d087.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_client_method
```

I think this has to do with anaconda since the following comands will trigger the same error.

```
conda install jupyter 
pip install jupyter
pip install python-igraph
```

I have already installed the libraries suggested by the answers to this question ([meet cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError when install pyopenssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093158/meet-cffi-ffiplatform-verificationerror-when-install-pyopenssl)). But it hasn't worked.