# python pip installing modules not working

Tags: python, pip

Using `windows` machine, `python 2.7`, `pip 9.0.1 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)`.

```
pip = 9.0.1
python = 2.7
os =  windows 10 Pro
```

while installing any package.

eg., `pip install pyopenssl`
throughs below error.

[image: SNIMissingWarning]

while trying easy_install.

eg., `easy_install PyOpenSSL`
throughs below error.

[image: easy-install]

Comment: Did you try "pip install requests[security]"?

Comment: did you update/upgade pip ? on which OS are you ? (and maybe have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340784/easy-install-pyopenssl-error)

Comment: @Dadep - I am using windows 10 Pro

Comment: Does `easy_install` fail for a similar reason?

Comment: @PrateekDewan I haven't used that. If I need to install pytest-runner it will be helpful?

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko I have updated easy install method error screenshot.

Comment: first  try `pip install urllib3[secure]` . May be it could work. Because this error comes usually by urllib3 package.

Comment: @Dhananjayan Python 2.x standard SSL module has some limitations to use SNI till this functionality was backported from 3.x in 2.7.9. PyOpenSSL installation may solve this issue. Try to get it directly from PyPi: `easy_install http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12.tar.gz`

Comment: @ChandaKorat it throws first screenshot error

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko it throws `error: Download error for http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12.tar.gz: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version`

Comment: @Dhananjayan, try to download the archive from the link and install it with pip from a local file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko It is not possible, every library has dependencies. whenever it needs to download library it throws download error as shown in the 2nd screenshot.

Comment: @phd It does not throws SNIMissing warning and download error.

Comment: @Dhananjayan Doesn't matter, really. It's an SSL error due to old SSL and old Python. Everything must be upgraded for `pip` to be usable.